# How to convert dataframe value into Map[String,List[String]]?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

I want to convert below dataframe into Map[String,List[String]]. I have changed initial dataframe to get Name columns in List format(using `collect_list`) but I am not able to convert it into `Map[String,List[String]]`.

DataFrame

```
+---------+-------+
|City     |  Name |
+---------+-------+
|Mumbai   |[A,B]  |
|Pune     |[C,D]  |
|Delhi    |[A,D]  |
+---------+-------+
```

Expected Output:

```
Map(Mumbai -> List(A,B), Pune -> List(C,D), Delhi-> List(A,D))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to rdd and collect as Map as below

```
val df = Seq(
  ("Mumbai", List("A", "B")),
  ("Pune", List("C", "D")),
  ("Delhi", List("A", "D"))
).toDF("city", "name")

val map: collection.Map[String, List[String]] =  df.rdd
  .map(row => (row.getAs[String]("city"), row.getAs[List[String]]("name")))
  .collectAsMap()
```

Hope this helps!